# I can't delete selected id data from database in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-sqlite

What should I do at this stage to delete the selected id? I tried all the ways I could think of. thanks

```
val db = this.writableDatabase
db.delete(table_name, null, null)


val db = this.writableDatabase
db.delete(table_name, "$col_id=?", arrayOf(itemId.toString()) )
    Toast.makeText(context, "Silindi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    db.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try executing a delete query like this

```
val sql = "DELETE FROM $table_name WHERE $col_id = $itemId"
db.execSQL(sql)
```

Then show the Toast message to indicate that the item has been deleted, and close the database connection afterwards.